# Transform T4 Templates

Tags: visual-studio, templates, t4

In Visual Studio, what does the menu command "Build" => "Transform All T4 Templates" do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

t4 is basically a tool built into VS for doing text transformation, typically for doing code generation. Transform All T4 Templates searches your solution for *.tt files and executes them to create other text, again typically source code, files.

Comment: where is "Transform All T4 Templates" on mac VS?